# libboost-1.49 dependency is not satisfiable

Tags: 14.04, boost, unsupported-packages

I am installing libboost-dev 1.49 from **https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/amd64/libboost-dev/1.49.0.1** which I require for some purposes.But I am getting following message

[image]

**Update**

On some research I got following reasons on the mentioned link

This package is a dependency package, which depends on Debian's default
 Boost version (currently 1.49).

Now How to proceed?

Comment: Debian 7 has Boost 1.49, you can use that. Any Ubuntu package you will find is unsuported and potentially suffers from bugs and other problems.

Comment: Although this question is not technically about an EOL release, it is about installing packages which come from an EOL release, so I'm flagging it as off-topic as well.

Comment: No it's OK, questions about installing packages which come from an EOL release are not off topic. There is even a tag for such questions called **unsupported-packages**.

Comment: Which software needs `libboost1.49-dev` as a dependency? It may be easier or more elegant to have it use 1.54 or 1.55 instead since they're included in the default package repositories of Ubuntu 14.04.